# Trying to install pathogen, but where?

Tags: error, installing, plugin-pathogen

I make a `.vim` directory in my home directory. I then made an `autoload` directory and a `bundle` directory. I added the `pathogen.vim` file to the autoload directory. I then added `execute pathogen#infect()` to my vimrc but there is a point I might have gone wrong. I have 3 different vimrc files, one in `/etc/vim`, one in `/usr/share/vim` and one in my home directory. Which one should I have edited? I have tried all 3 but it still doesn't work, and I'm getting errors:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line 1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Can anyone help?

More generally, when I want to edit my vimrc, where should I do this? in `/etc/vim/vimrc`? in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`? in `~/vim/vimrc`? or just `~/vimrc`?

Comment: looks like pathogen is not installed. What have you done? Can you please show your directory structure? Did you follow the [installation instruction](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#installation)?

Comment: Use the one in your home directory. The others should NOT be touched.

Comment: OK, but should I now restore the other ones to their default settings or leave them alone?

Comment: You need to revert your system-wide vimrc to its pristine state.

Comment: `~/vimrc` is a typo? Should be `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - restore all vimrc files except for the one in ~/.vimrc to their defaults.